# mysql multiple IN clauses linked by AND clauses in the same field

Tags: mysql

I need to put together a query than gives me all versions that have different trims. Each trim type may be defined by several trim_ids.

My attempt below was to say: give me all versions that have any type of power window AND manual air conditioner AND any type of air bags and so on.

The number of AND clauses is variable depending upon user input.

Of course this query is not working. Actually it works but gives me an empty result set.

Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT *
FROM vprice_range
INNER JOIN versiontrim USING ( version_id )
WHERE versiontrim.trim_id IN ( 139, 152, 237, 265, 266 ) == types of power window
AND versiontrim.trim_id IN ( 39 )  == manual air conditioner
.....
AND versiontrim.trim_id IN (45, 55, 154)  == types of air bags
GROUP BY version_id
```

Comment: why you separate the ids, when using one field?

Comment: bksi.This depends upon user input. User may choose to filter for power window AND for air bags, or any combination thereof.

Comment: Is that not an `OR` instead of an `AND`?

Comment: then you should use OR instead AND

Comment: bkwi. Within the IN clauses it is certainly OR but for the other trim it is AND. The condition is: it can be any, ie OR, within that trim, but then it has to be AND the other trim. If I use OR for the other trim I will have more and more versions that fit the criteria, but the reality is that for each new trim you will have less and less versions. So AND it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you'll need one of two queries...  Your choice of preference.  One version is to use multiple aliases, another is based on counts.. Personally, I prefer the multiple joins as:

```
    SELECT 
          PR.*
       FROM 
          vprice_range PR
             JOIN versiontrim Windows
                on PR.Version_ID = Windows.Version_ID
               AND Windows.Trim_ID IN ( 139, 152, 237, 265, 266 )

             JOIN versiontrim HasAir
                on PR.Version_ID = HasAir.Version_ID
               AND HasAir.Trim_ID IN ( 39 )

             JOIN versiontrim AirBags
                on PR.Version_ID = AirBags.Version_ID
               AND AirBags.Trim_ID IN ( 45, 55, 154 )
   group by
      PR.Version_ID
```

Your group by on version, but based on SQL engine (MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc), you may have issue for other columns... you may need to just DISTINCT PR.Version_ID to resolve.